# A tensor category need not be isomorphic to a strict tensor category

Tags: ct.category-theory, group-cohomology, monoidal-categories, tensor-products

This question was originally posted on MSE, but got no answer even after putting a bounty on it, so I'll try here.

---

I'm reading the book "Tensor categories" by Etingof, Gelaki, Nikshych, and Ostrik. In remark 2.8.6 (posted below), it is claimed that the category $\mathcal{C}_G^\omega$ (defined in example 2.3.8, also below) is not isomorphic to a strict tensor category whenever $\omega$ is not cohomologically trivial. Can someone explain this a bit more?

If someone knows another example of a tensor category that is not isomorphic to a strict tensor category, I'm also interested in that.

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First consider the category $\mathcal{C}_G$ with its bifunctor $\otimes$ and unit. How many ways are there to enhance this to a monoidal category structure? The missing data are precisely the associators. The associators will be a choice of map

$$a_{\delta_g, \delta_h, \delta_m}: (\delta_g \otimes \delta_h) \otimes \delta_m \to \delta_g \otimes (\delta_h \otimes \delta_m)$$

for each $g,h,m \in G$. However in $\mathcal{C}_G$, the hom spaces are identified with $A$. Thus the associator amounts to an assignment of elements $\omega(g,h,m) \in A$ for each triple $g,h,m \in G$. Now the associator is required to satisfy some equations, such as the pentagon equation. Written in terms of the $\omega$, the pentagon equation is equivalent to saying that $\omega$ satisfies the cocycle condition, which we might write as $\delta  \omega= 0$. (It should actually be a normalized cocycle because of the unit triangle equations, but lets ignore that).

When are two of these structures isomorphic? For that we need a tensor isomorphism. Assume for simplicity that it is the identity on objects and morphisms and preserves the $\otimes$ bifunctor strictly. This is not really a restriction as we could use the isomorphism to make this identification. There is still another piece of data, which is a collection of isomorphisms:

$$f_{\delta_g, \delta_h}: F(\delta_g) \otimes F(\delta_h) \to F(\delta_g \otimes \delta_h)$$

for each pair $g,h \in G$. As before we can identify this with a collection of elements $c(f,g) \in A$ for each pair $g,h \in G$. These are required to satisfy a hexagon identity which involves the two associators. When written in terms of these elements, this becomes:

$$\omega_1 - \omega_2 = \delta c$$

So that the two cocycles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ differ by a cochain. In summary if two of these monoidal structures are related by an isomorphism of tensor categories, the two cocycles must be cohomologous.

Note: to be strict, means that the corresponding cocycle is the trivial cocycle. Putting this together we see that to be isomorphic to a strict tensor category requires that the underlying cocycle be cohomologically trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went through it and I have two additional questions. (1) Etingof writes that the unit axiom is trivial, but I believe we need the additional hypothesis that the $3$-cocycle is normalised, i.e. that it satisfies $\omega(g,1,h)$ is the identity for all $g,h \in G$. Is that correct?

(2) Do you know an example of a group with a cohomologically non-trivial normalised $3$-cocycle? I'm not very familiar with group cohomology. 

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you that if your unitors are trivial, then you need to use normalized cocycles. Fortunately normalized cocycles compute the same group cohomology as unnormalized cocycles. There are many non-trivial examples. Degree 3-cohomology corresponds to "crossed modules", which you can google to get more information and examples. Probably the easiest non-trivial example is when $G=\mathbb{Z}/n$. Then $H^3(G; A)$ is the n-torsion subgroup of $A$ (here we take A to have trivial $G$ action). Each non-trivial element is represented by a non-trivial normalized 3-cocycle.

Comment: If you allow non-trivial unitors as well, then things are more complicated. It is true that then any cocycle can be used. The 3-cocyclce _almost_ determines the unitors. The associator and unitors are determined by the 3-cocycle plus the value $\rho_1 = \lambda_1$ of the  unitor on the unit object (which can be non-trivial in general). Then you have to consider these up to monoidal isomorphism, and the first step might be to show that without changing the cocycle you can always reduce to the case that $\rho_1 = \lambda_1$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With unitors you mean the natural isomorphisms $I \otimes X\cong X \cong X \otimes I?$ These are the identities in my case.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by unitors.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! Maybe one more question: do you have a reference for your claim that the normalized cocycles compute the same group cohomology as the unnormalized ones?

Comment: This is part of the general yoga of the Dold-Kan correspondence between cosimplicial abelian groups and cochain complexes. There are two ways to go from a cosimplicial abelian group to cochains. You either use the Moore complex (whose differential is the alternating sum of the face maps) or using the normalized Moore complex. The latter is an equivalence of categories, but both complexes have the same cohomology. A reference for the chain/simplicial ab-group case can be read here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Moore+complex see thm 3.3.

Comment: Splendid! Thanks again!